# Get the elements with same name zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i have a scenario where i am adding multiple qualifications, i am saving the values in hidden fields like

```
 $("<input/>",{type:'hidden',value:deg,name:'degree[]'}).attr("data-deg",deg).appendTo("form");

$("<input/>",{type:'hidden',value:year,name:'year[]'}).attr("data-year",year).appendTo("form");

$("<input/>",{type:'hidden',value:inst,name:'inst[]'}).attr("data-inst",inst).appendTo("form");
```

if i do var_dump it shows me the following output

```
["degree"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "M.Sc" [1]=> string(4) "B.Sc" }
```

in the controller im getting it like

```
$Degree = $form->getValue('degree[]');
```

but var_dump($Degree) gives me NULL, how can i get the values plz help

EDIT

here is my form looks like

```
$degreename = $this->createElement('select', 'degreename')
        ->setRequired(true);
        $degreename->removeDecorator('label');
        $degreename->removeDecorator('htmlTag');
        $degreename->removeDecorator('Errors');
        $ddloptions = $this->db->GetDegrees();
        $degreename->setMultiOptions($ddloptions);
        $degreename->addMultiOptions(array(
                '0'=>'--Select Degree--'
        ));
        $degreename->setValue(0);


        $passingyear = $this->createElement('select', 'passingyear')
        ->setRequired(true);
        $passingyear->removeDecorator('label');
        $passingyear->removeDecorator('htmlTag');
        $passingyear->removeDecorator('Errors');
        $passingyear->addMultiOptions(array(
                '0'=>'--Select Passing Year--',
                '1950'=>'1950',
                '1951'=>'1951',
                '1952'=>'1952',
        )
        );
        $passingyear->setValue('0');


$institute = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('institute');
$institute->setRequired(false)
->addFilter('StripTags')
->addFilter('StringTrim');
$institute->removeDecorator('label');
$institute->removeDecorator('htmlTag');
$institute->removeDecorator('Errors');
```

though the `degreename` and the `passing year` are required they always has the value `0` `institute` i have set to `false` the user can add multiple qualifications and upon each user selection i add a hidden field like shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$Degree = $form->getValue('degree'); 
'degree[]' is not a proper key in php and the POST request
```

**UPDATE1:**
Your Javascript piece for the hidden elements still puzzles me a bit and I wonder if you have a "degree" element in $form. To get a final answer it might be good to know what you use inside your $form.

If you just need the submitted data (as is) you are just fine getting the information from $_POST. You wouldn't need Zend_Form for that.

**UPDATE2:**
Now seeing your form code the fog if lifting; you are missing the elements for you hidden elements. When you call `isValid($_POST)` you have nothing in the form to validate the data. Calling `getValue('degree')` or actually any of the hidden element will return NULL.

If you just want the data you will be fine with just $_POST but that is not really secure data handling. Zend_Form elements allow you to add filters and validators for sanitizing the data. For that you have to either create the hidden elements with Zend_Form (use Javascript only to add the values) or have elements in your form you use only for validation. You can use something like `if ( !empty($_POST) )` to added them for validation.

Comment: `degree` didnt work thats why  i tried `degree[]`  any how i fetched the values via `$_POST['degree']`

Comment: then I guess you haven't used `$form->isValid($_POST)` first?

Comment: come to think of it now and as a matter of fact i did use `$form->isValid($_POST)` i have searched the web looking for answers to get the multiple values from form post in array like syntax that involved some pre- work to be done that i couldn't afford to do so i used simply `$_POST`, let me get back to home and confirm whether i marked the fields as required or not but i think i did marked them required...+1 for your time `:)`

Comment: @john Love to take the time but strangely enough many are looking for a one hit wonder in an answer. See the update in my answer.

Comment: though i have solved the problem using `$_POST` i have updated the question with my form code, its my first project with zend i used zend form to do the things zend way, using subforms also crossed my mind but that was too much and the dead line was approaching :)

Comment: @john I've added my Zend way for this

Answer (score 2):

When you create instance of degree then do set it as array

```
  $degree = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('degree');
  $degree->setIsArray(true);
```

Now `$form->degree->getValue() ; //will return array ;`